# UITableView single clicks

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UITableView and UINavigationController, and I'd like to distinguish between two clicks: 1) normal click that selects a row and 2) a click that happens ANYWHERE else on the screen (other than the buttons on the UINavigationController). I wrote this code:

```
singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapHandler:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
```

The problem with this however is that it overrides the normal clicks that select a row.

Comment: It's not clear what "ANYWHERE else on the screen" means.  Does the table view take up the whole screen below the navigation bar?  Do you mean you want a touch on a table view row to both select the row *and* trigger your tap recognizer?

Comment: The table view takes up the whole screen below the navigation bar. I want a touch on a table view row ONLY to select the row. A touch elsewhere should ONLY trigger the tap recognizer. And a button push on the navigation bar should trigger ONLY the button push handlers. Is that clearer?

Comment: It sounds like the only part of the screen where you want to recognize taps is in the navigation bar, outside of the buttons.  Correct?

Comment: Correct. Although valid and non-valid rows will have a different outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're putting the tap recognizer on either the `UIWindow` itself, or the window's sole subview.  You need to give the tap recognizer a delegate, and that delegate needs to implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`.

In that method, you want to return `NO` if the touch is in a button or if the touch is in a table view cell, and `YES` otherwise.  You need to walk up the view hierarchy, starting with the view that the touch landed in, looking for either of those classes.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    for (UIView *view = touch.view; view; view = view.superview) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            return NO;
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```